# How to pipe a default file on node request error?

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, request

I'm using nodejs with the [request](https://github.com/request/request) package.

**Situation:**

1. My frontend sends a file request to my node server through a HTTP GET
2. The server check if the user is authenticated
3. The server requests the file on AWS S3 like so:

   ```
   request(req.query.url)
      .on('error', (e) => {
       // Some code here?
       res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../assets/favicon.png'))
      })
      .pipe(res)
   ```

**Problem**: Sometimes it doesn't find the file or can't connect to AWS S3 or whatever the error is, I would like to send  a default file if that happens. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn`t it be a little cleaner if you start using try/catch instead of promises?
like:

```
try {
    response = request(req.query.url)
    pipe(res)
catch (e) {
    console.log("just so you can know why it failed")
    pipe(default)
}
```